# The arithmetic function $\frac{\operatorname{rad}(2n)}{n+\varphi(n)+1}$ and a characterization of twin primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, totient-function

We denote the Euler's totient function as $\varphi(n)$, and the radical of the integer $n> 1$ as
$$\operatorname{rad}(n)=\prod_{\substack{p\mid n\\ p\text{ prime}}}p,$$
taking $\operatorname{rad}(1)=1$ that is this definition from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer).

Then it is easy to prove the following claim (I don't know if this characterization of odd primes is in the literature).

**Claim.** An integer $n\geq 1$ is an odd prime if and only if satisfies $$\operatorname{rad}(2n)=n+\varphi(n)+1\tag{1}.$$

*Proof.* The difficult implication is by cases.$\square$

Then I wanted to use previous claim to get a characterization of twin primes. Because defining the arithmetic function $$f(n)=\frac{\operatorname{rad}(2n)}{n+\varphi(n)+1}\tag{2}$$
it is obvious that each twin prime pair $(n,n+2)$ solves the equation  $$f(n)=f(n+2).\tag{3}$$

I would like to know what about the other implication as the next question.

> **Question.** Prove or refute that if an integer $m\geq 1$ satisfies $(3)$, that is  $$\frac{\operatorname{rad}(2m)}{m+\varphi(m)+1}=\frac{\operatorname{rad}(2m+4)}{m+\varphi(m+2)+3}$$
>   then $m$ and $m+2$ are primes (that is, thus $m$ is the lesser of a twin prime pair, sequence *A001359* from the OEIS). **Many thanks.**

Feel free to add what work can be done, if you cann't provide us a full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Claim:**$\;$If $n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ is such that $f(n) = f(n+2)$, then $n$ is an odd prime.

**Proof:**

For convenience, the proof will be organized as a sequence of sub-claims, as listed below . . .

$\;\;\;(1)\;\,$If $p^2|n$, for some odd prime $p$, then $f(n) \ne f(n-2)$, and $f(n) \ne f(n+2)$.

$\;\;\;(2)\;\,$If $n$ is odd, but not prime, then $f(n) \ne f(n+2)$

$\;\;\;(3)\;\,$If $n$ is a multiple of $4$, then $f(n) < \frac{1}{2}$.

$\;\;\;(4)\;\,$If $n$ is even and squarefree, then $f(n) \ge \frac{1}{2}$.

$\;\;\;(5)\;\,$If $n$ is even, then $f(n) \ne f(n+2)$

**Proof of $(1)$:**

Suppose $p^2|n$, for some odd prime $p$.

For $k\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, let $a(k),b(k)$ be the numerator and denominator, respectively, of $f(k)\;$, when reduced to lowest terms.

From $p^2{\mid}n$, we get $p{\mid}\phi(n)$, hence $p{\not\mid}b(n)$.

It follows that $p{\mid}a(n)$.

From $p{\mid}n$, we get $p{\not\mid}(n-2)$, and $p{\not\mid}(n+2)$, hence $p{\not\mid}a(n-2)$, and $p{\not\mid}a(n+2)$.

It follows that $f(n) \ne f(n-2)$, and $f(n) \ne f(n+2)$.

This completes the proof of $(1)$.

**Proof of $(2)$:**

Suppose $n$ is odd, not prime, and $f(n) = f(n+2)$.

Note that $f(1) \ne f(3)$, hence $n > 1$.

Since $n$ is not prime, we have $\phi(n) < n-1$.

From $(1)$, it follows that $n$ and $n+2$ are squarefree, hence ${\text{rad}}(2n)=2n$, and ${\text{rad}}(2(n+2)) = 2(n+2)$.

Let $x=\phi(n)$, and let $y=\phi(n+2)$.

Then from $f(n) = f(n+2)$, we get
$$
\frac{2n}{n+x + 1} = \frac{2n+4}{n+y+3}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;\;\,
$$
which yields
$$
n = \frac{2(x+1)}{y-x}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;
$$
It follows that $y > x$, hence, since $x,y$ are necessarily both even, we get $y-x \ge 2$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;n &= \frac{2(x+1)}{y-x}\\[4pt]
&\le \frac{2(x+1)}{2}&&\text{[since $y-x \ge 2$]}\\[4pt]
&= x+1\\[4pt]
&=\phi(n)+1\\[4pt]
&< (n-1) + 1&&\text{[since $\phi(n) < n-1$]}\\[4pt]
&=n\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
contradiction.

This completes the proof of $(2)$.

**Proof of $(3)$:**

Suppose $n$ is a multiple of $4$.

Then from $2n = 8{\left({\large{\frac{n}{4}}}\right)}$, we get $\text{rad}(2n) \le {\large{\frac{n}{2}}}$, hence
$$
f(n)=\frac{\text{rad}(2n)}{n+\phi(n)+1} <  \frac{\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{n}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
This completes the proof of $(3)$.

**Proof of $(4)$:**

Suppose $n$ is even and squarefree.

Then $\text{rad}(2n) = n$, hence
$$
f(n)=\frac{\text{rad}(2n)}{n+\phi(n)+1} \ge \frac{n}{n+(n-1)+1} =\frac{1}{2}
$$
This completes the proof of $(4)$.

**Proof of $(5)$:**

Suppose $n$ is even.

If at least one of $n,\,n+2$ is divisible by the square of an odd prime, then by $(1)$, we get $f(n) \ne f(n+2)$, and we're done.

Thus, we can assume neither of $n,\,n+2$ is divisible by the square of an odd prime.

It follows that one of $n,\,n+2$ is a multiple of $4$, and the other is even and squarefree, hence by $(3)$ and $(4)$, we get $f(n) \ne f(n+2)$, and again we're done.

This completes the proof of $(5)$.

From the truth of $(2)$ and $(5)$, the truth of the main claim follows.

Comment: Many thanks tomorrow in the morning I am going to study your nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think my previous answer leads to an immediate full resolution of your question.

You showed that $f(n)=1$ if and only if $n$ is an odd prime.

Thus, if $n$ and $n+2$ are twin primes, we get 
$$f(n)=f(n+2)=1$$
Conversely, suppose $f(n)=f(n+2)$, for some positive integer $n$.

Then from my previous answer, $n$ must be an odd prime.

Since $n$ is an odd prime, we get $f(n)=1$.

But then from $f(n)=f(n+2)$, we get $f(n+2)=1$, hence $n+2$ is an odd prime.

Therefore $n$ and $n+2$ are twin primes.

Thus, we have:

- If $n$ is a positive integer, then $f(n)=f(n+2)$ if and only if $n$ and $n+2$ are twin primes.

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification.